# Proving $X$ is compact using a function $f\colon X \to Y$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, open-map, closed-map

Let's suppose I have a topological space $X$, for which I am trying to prove its compactness. If I construct a function $f: X \to Y$ to another topological space $Y$, **what are some examples of conditions** on $f$ and $Y$ that could guarantee that $X$ is compact?

E.g. if $f$ is open and injective, and $f(X)$ is compact, then $X$ is compact [1]. One could prove the compactness of $f(X)$ by showing $Y$ is compact and $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is closed.

Does assuming that either $X$ or $Y$ are Hausdorff / metrisable help?

[1] This seems dual to the theorem that continuous images of compact spaces are compact.

Comment: Not sure if one can weaken the condition to: $f$ is open and $f^{-1} (y)$ is uniformly bounded. That $f$ be open seems to be necessary

Comment: @ArcticChar: I'd say openness of $f$ is necessary, since we need to be able to map open covers in $X$ to open covers in $Y$ to use the compactness of $Y$. Uniformly bounded requires $X$ to be a metric space?

Answer (score 1):

The other way round is easier: if we can have a continuous $f: Y \to X$ that is *onto* and *continuous* and $Y$ is compact then so is $X$. E.g. that's why the image of a path is always compact.

For your case $f: X \to Y$ we could use $f$ perfect: continuous, closed, onto and all fibres compact (so all sets of the form $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ are compact); then $Y$ compact implies $X$ is too. This can be used to see that $X \times Y$ is compact whenever $X$ and $Y$ are (using the projection maps).

Comment: Is the condition that $f$ be onto superfluous? $f$ is onto when you restrict the codomain to $f(X)$, so if $f$ closed and $Y$ compact, then $f(X)$ is closed, hence compact...

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett You could ditch it if you liked, if indeed $f[X]$ is closed in $Y$ (some texts assume that closed maps are always onto). Then the co-restricted version of $f$ is subject to my quoted theorem.